# How can I change the contents of a dropdown list dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have a pair of dropdown lists, they are linked in the sense that in it is basically a 2-d array.  I have a list of accounts, and a list of domains for each account.  So based on which account the user selects from the dropdown, I need to populate the domain list with the appropriate selections.  Is there a way I can do this without doing a postback?

```
Private Sub Account_Select(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AccountName_Dropdown.SelectedIndexChanged
    Hostname_Dropdown.Items.Clear()
    Dim cur_hostnames As Collection = CType(hostnames(AccountName_Dropdown.SelectedIndex), Collection)
    For i As Integer = 0 To cur_hostnames.Count
        Hostname_Dropdown.Items.Add(New ListItem(CStr(cur_hostnames(i))))
    Next
End Sub
```

I don't presently have the data to access, so I just constructed a collection of collections `hostnames` that contains a bunch of integers

I'm somewhat new to asp and vb.net programming, so please forgive terrible coding practices if they exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [CascadingDropDown](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) control from the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/Default.aspx).

Comment: Maybe a really dumb question, how do I add the Ajax stuff to my project?  When I try and declare it in my layout VS doesn't know what ajaxToolkit is

Comment: Check the Tutorial: http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/get-started-with-the-ajax-control-toolkit-vb

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your dropdownlist with an asp:updatepanel. Add autopostback=true to your dropdown and on the selectedindexchanged event, rebind your 2nd dropdown.

Hope this helps.